# Looping through to a placeholder text block and joining each block of text

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop from an array to a block of text with placeholders with Python. However I can't figure out how too append or join the blocks of text under the previous block of text.

How do I loop through an array into a text block with placeholders then output the individual text blocks on top of each other.

My array looks like:

```
[{'name': James, 'age': 40},{'name': Frank, 'age': 29}]
```

My placeholder template:

```
f'''

Profile - 
Name: {name}
Age: {age}

'''
```

I am trying to get to output

```
Profile -
Name: James
Age: 40

Profile -
Name: Frank
Age: 28
```

I have tried using both join and concatenation - to no avail i.e:

```
textBlock = ""
for i in data:

   text = f'''Name: {i{'name']}<br>Age: {i{'age']}<br>'''

   textBlock.join(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was this part `{i{'name']}` it should be `{i['name']}` Here try this:

```py
data = [{'name': 'James', 'age': 40},{'name': 'Frank', 'age': 29}]

result = '\n'.join(f'''Name: {i['name']}<br>Age: {i['age']}<br>''' for i in data)
print(result)
```